# Clean way to create an aggregate total of columns in multiple DataRows

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a series of DataRow objects, each with a bunch of different fields.  What I want to do is create a new DataRow object with the total of certain decimal fields.  Right now, my code looks something like this:

```
DataRow tally = myTable.NewRow();

foreach (DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
{
   if (row["SomeField"] != DBNull.Value)
      tally["SomeField"] = (tally["SomeField"] is DBNull ? 0 : (Decimal)tally["SomeField"]) + (Decimal)row["SomeField"];

   // ...     
}
```

I need to do the same with about 20 other fields, but I think the code is incredibly messy due to all the type-casting and null checking.  Is there perhaps a way to refactor this code to be a bit more readable?

Note: I only want to tally up certain columns, otherwise I'd probably just loop through the columns in the DataRow rather than repeating the above code 20 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move your calculation code into a new method:

```
private void Tally(DataRow tally, DataRow row, int index)
{
    if (row[index] != DBNull.Value)
    {
        tally[index] = (tally[index] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (decimal)tally[index]) + (decimal)row[index];
    }
}
```

and use an array of indexes for the columns you want to tally:

```
DataRow tally = myTable.NewRow();

int[] indexes = new int[] { 0, 2 };

foreach(DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
{
    foreach(int index in indexes)
    {
        Tally(tally, row, index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea I'm actually considering this approach (only with an array of strings, since I hate hard-coding in column indexes)..  It does make stuff a bit less ugly for sure.

Comment: This ended up being the cleanest way I could find too.  I loop through an array of strings and call my "messy" code once per iteration.  I decided not to overthink it with LINQ, since I want to control the loop myself instead of doing a bunch of O(n) LINQ calls.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example if you want to do it with LINQ.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Desc", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(decimal));
table.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));

table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Product", 1, 2 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Product", 2, 10 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Product", 3, null });

var totalQty = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(l => l.Field<string>("Desc"))
    .Select(r =>
        new {   Desc = r.Key,
                TotalQty = r.Sum(w => w.Field<decimal?>("Qty")),
                TotalPrice = r.Sum(w => w.Field<decimal?>("Price")),
        });
```

Will yield and object with three properties.  Note that you need to cast the `decimal` column to `decimal?` to support any null values that may occur in the table.

```
Desc = "Product", TotalQty = 6, TotalPrice = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to DataSets and Sum:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb738016#sumsimp

Comment: I kinda want to avoid that because I'm already looping through my DataSet anyway to write out each row, a LINQ expression would cause me to iterate again through the dataset to then get the totals.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Compute method of the DataTable class: [DataTable.Compute method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx).